# GAP programming: variable assignment and functions

Tags: math, gap-system

This question is about the GAP and the GAP programming language:

I would like to write code that will compute the following formula:

```
(n^+1)/GcdInt(n^2+1, 2^(Tau(n^2+1)));
```

for the first 100,000 integers n.

Here is what I have so far:

```
f:=function(n);
f:=(n^+1)/GcdInt(n^2+1, 2^(Tau(n^2+1)));
return f;
end;
```

It is grossly wrong. I cannot find any good sources on writing GAP code that I can understand unfortunately.

Comment: First, there should be no semicolon after `function(n);`. Second, there is a typo in `(n^+1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it:

```
for i in [1..100000] do
    Print((i^2+1)/GcdInt(i^2+1,2^Tau(i^2+1)), " ");
od;
Print( "\n" );
```

Comment: This code can be used in the GAP command line. If you need to put it into a function, the syntax is explained in the [GAP Carpentries-style lesson](https://carpentries-incubator.github.io/gap-lesson/03-func/index.html) and in the [GAP Tutorial](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/tut/chap4.html).